# CSS Keyframes are executing on elements without required class on mobile devices only

Tags: android, html, ios, css, debugging

I have been working to debug an issue with an ecommerce site I am building. I currently have keyframes executing with the class fadeRight. The fadeRight class executes a sliding in effect from the right on page load. I have this class only applied to a few elements and it works perfectly.

My issue is when I load the homepage only on a mobile phone, the navbar logo and shopping cart like in just like the elements below it with the fadeRight class.

I have tested it out on a few androids and ios devices and the effect is clear. I cannot replicate this on my PC running IE and Chrome as well as my Mac running Safari and Chrome. I do not know what an accurate debugging solution would be that would be causing this issue. I have set my chrome options to mobile size under dev tools thinking it would react like my phone, but nope.

The site I am working on is here: [store](http://store.revivesalonsf.com/)

Comment: I can replicate it on a mac using Chrome Dev Tools. When you have dev tools open, click the 'Toggle device" icon which looks like a phone/tablet. Hope that helps with the debugging

Comment: Please post your code (HTML and CSS, and JavaScript if any).

Comment: I will add more information now that I can replicate it on my mac only using chrome dev tools. Now I have to figure out where the issue is originating from before posting code. @freginold

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @bldev difficult one to debug and replicate. Adding overflow: hidden to #tile-group has solved it for me, so I image its layout related

Comment: @JamesKing Wow that did work and I published the change. I will work tonight to figure out the actual cause of this by removing the added overflow: hidden from #tile-group. I may need to touch up on my knowledge in the overflow and keyframes relationship and add some information back here with the root cause. Thanks